# When is a job posting not a job posting?

Tags: discussion, jobs

The following post: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/86436/software-engineer-lead-software-engineer-sep

Says that they have:

> "openings for software engineers, lead software engineers and senior
>   software engineers. ... in areas like life science, medical, aerospace
>   and more... experience with mainstream development technologies (.NET,
>   Ruby, Java, etc.)"

This certainly appears to **not** be a single position that could be upgraded dependent on experience. How is it that three (or more) separate positions are allowed to share a single posting?  I thought that Careers was supposed to be better than all the other boards where the same group of recruiting companies keep constantly re-posting the same four jobs.

Am I simply misguided, needing a pointer to a specific posting guideline that says this is okay?

Comment: With no comment on the supposed purpose of careers.so it's common to have openings at multiple levels within an organisation. This doesn't seem that unusual.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, Joshua. You're absolutely correct in that we only allow a listing to advertise for a single position. Multiple seniority levels are allowed, so long as years of experience are the only changing requirements. This particular listing does appear to break this rule, so we will reach out to SEP and ask them to revise their listing.

In regards to your comment about the quality of listings found on Careers, we do our best internally to monitor postings, but as our board continues to grow, it's simply not feasible for the few of us in charge of quality control to police every one. This is why we include the "Flag a problem" feature, in hopes that the community will lend a helping hand and inform us of issues that we may miss.

Comment: I looked for the flag feature, however I missed it.  I'll look harder next time should I run across another one.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake it's in the right sidebar, below the various sharing options. Maybe not ideal location, but can't really think of a better place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Man, I don't see how I missed it, though the thin outline of the flag and my old man eyes may have conspired together.

Answer (score 9):

The [house rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules) are quite clear about all-in-one job advertisements:

> **3. One position and one location per job listing.**
>   Multiple positions need to go into multiple job listings. If you are a recruiting firm posting on behalf of your client, then your client needs to be named as the employer and your role in the process needs to be explained.

This seems a very broad catch-all job advertisement and I don't think it is allowed to do this.